# Eliminate matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does $A \cdot$ $A^T$ cancel each other?

I am partly trying to understand how linear least square works..
I see that that the projection is the closest solution given as $Ax^*$ but do not see why $A^T$ should be multiplied on to it other than it will cancel out with A, and make $x = A^Tb$

Comment: Does $AA^T = I$?

Comment: its a general case..

Answer (score 0):

In general $A^T \neq A^{-1}$. Even in the scalar case, $a^2 \neq 1$ unless $a = 1$.

If $A^T A = A A^T = I$, $A$ is called an orthogonal matrix. In general, the least square method is equivalent to solving the normal equation $A^TAx = A^Tb$. The final equation $x = A^T b$ is only true in the special case of $A$ being an orthogonal matrix.

Further, if you are interested in the equivalence of the least square method and the normal equation, you can read my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314568/least-square-solution-with-the-transposed-matrix/1314587#1314587.

Answer (score 0):

We do not multiply both sides by $A^T$ to "cancel out the $A$".

The real idea here is that given the system $Ax = b$, the system $A^TAx = A^Tb$ is a new system.  Solving this new system won't give us the solutions to the original equation (in particular if $A$ is not invertible).  Rather, solving this new equation will give us the *least squares* solutions to the original problem.

This is a sensible thing to do because the least squares problem (the new equation) will *always* have a solution, so we can always find a solution $x$ for this new equation.  In fact, a lot of the time, $A$ will not be a square matrix, but $A^TA$ is always square and might even have an inverse.

As for *why* solving this new equation solves the least-squares problem, [see a few derivations here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations).

Comment: But aren't A and $A^T$ orthongonal => thereby ending up with a I matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by "$A$ and $A^T$ are orthogonal"?

Comment: It is certainly not usually true that $A A^T = I$.

Comment: I am confused.. Isn't that the principle at which least square solution.. 
That an projection of vector b = A $\cdot$ $x^*$ such that  A^T and A*$x^*$ end up being the $I$$x^*$

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking

Comment: I been watching videos on khan about the stuff.. As he explained it is the best approximation the projection of b on to the column space of the matrix A. This projection can be defined as  $A \cdot x^*$ and it orthogonal matrix must be $A^T$  multiplied gives $I$ matrix

Comment: What does the term "orthogonal matrix" mean to you?

Comment: The matrix itself is not orthogonal but the vector made by proj b - b is orthogonal with A*$x^*$... but the transposed.. it confuses me now..